# Multiple RequestFactory servlets for a single GWT application

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Is it possible to have this?
And how can this be achieved?

The motivation - I want one secured (SSL) service for user-provisioning (passwords...), and one non-secured.

Comment: This post might be related to your needs also

[Authentication in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047925/gwt-requestfactory-authentication-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashwin Desikan answered my question on http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/

Quote:

---

Gilad, 
You can have multiple RequestFactoryServlets. check out the example below. 
If you look at it closely, I have a different url mapping. You will have 
to define individual  RequestTransports to be associated with the 
url-mapping in your client.

Also, you will have to controll operations exposed by each of the 
requestFactories in your client. You can always have a base factory 
where you can provide common functions and move only the secured ones to 
SecuredRequestFactory

What I would recommend with this approach is, before using the 
RequestFactories have a check in your code to determine if a user is 
loggedIn. If logged in use the secure servlet for all requests.

example ;

*web.xml *

```
<filter> 
<filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>com.example.server.gae.GaeAuthFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 
<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name> 
<servlet-name>authRequestFactory</servlet-name> 
</filter-mapping> 
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>authRequestFactory</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryS ervlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>unAuthRequestFactory</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryS ervlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>unAuthRequestFactory</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/unsignedRequest</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>authRequestFactory</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/signedRequest</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

*client*

```
*//AuthenticatedRequestTransport* 

public class AuthenticatedRequestTransport extends DefaultRequestTransport { 
     /** 
      * default constructor. 
      * 
      */ 
     public AuthenticatedRequestTransport() { 
         super(); 
         //set the url 
         String requestURL = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "signedRequest"; 
         setRequestUrl(requestURL); 
     } 
} 

*//Un-Authenticated Request* 
public class UnAuthenticatedRequestTransport extends 
DefaultRequestTransport { 
     public UnAuthenticatedRequestTransport() { 
         super(); 
         //set the url 
         String requestURL = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "unsignedRequest"; 
         setRequestUrl(requestURL); 
     } 
}
```

regards 
Ashwin