# GWT RequestFactory authentication functions

Tags: gwt, authentication, requestfactory

I'm using GWT and RequestFactory on a new project that needs authentication.

Where would be the best place to add the login and logout functions ? in a UserRequestContext ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use servlet filter.

I split RequestFactory calls into two streams - one for unauthenticated calls and another one for authenticated ones. Here is piece of my `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CustomRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.server.CustomRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CustomRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CustomRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequestAuth</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then I created servlet filter which looks like this:

```
public class GaeAuthFilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        if (!userService.isUserLoggedIn())
        {
            String returnURI = "/";

            String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
            String refererURI = request.getHeader("Referer");
            if (requestURI.equals("/gwtRequestAuth"))
            {
                if (refererURI != null)
                    returnURI = refererURI;
            } else
                returnURI = requestURI;

            response.setHeader("login", userService.createLoginURL(returnURI));
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }

        LoginService.login(request);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

As you can see I set `login` http-header with URL to auth webpage.

In the client code I intercept it by implementing my own [DefaultRequestTransport](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/client/DefaultRequestTransport.html) that looks ike this:

```
public class GaeAuthRequestTransport extends DefaultRequestTransport
{
    private final EventBus eventBus;

    public GaeAuthRequestTransport(EventBus eventBus)
    {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestCallback createRequestCallback(final TransportReceiver receiver)
    {
        final RequestCallback superCallback = super.createRequestCallback(receiver);

        return new RequestCallback()
        {
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
            {
                if (Response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED == response.getStatusCode())
                {
                    String loginUrl = response.getHeader("login");
                    if (loginUrl != null)
                    {
                        receiver.onTransportFailure(new ServerFailure(
                                "Unauthenticated user", null, null, false /* not fatal */));
                        eventBus.fireEvent(new GaeAuthenticationFailureEvent(loginUrl));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                superCallback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
            }

            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
            {
                superCallback.onError(request, exception);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Fired event is handled in the client code that navigates browser to login URL.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm ok with the way you use to separate protected and not protected data. But my question is more concerning the location of those authentication functions. Would you recommand to add them to your user EntityProxy or add it somewhere else ? in a dedicated ValueProxy ?

Comment: There are number of options. You can have separate login page like in my example above. Or you can create login()/logout() function in your RequestContext interface. First option is more old school, second option is more AJAX :)

Comment: Thanks ruslan. Ok I must admit my first question is not very clear but I want to use requestfactory for authentication functions. Consequently I'm speaking about your second option and to be clear I'm looking for best practises to achieve that.

Comment: Good luck and feel free to post more RF questions here :) And don't forget to mark people's answers as correct (when they're correct) so it improves your rating.

Comment: Coming here from another question, so I'm very late to the party. Note that your "unfiltered" RequestFactoryServlet will happily serve the exact same data and service methods as the filtered one, so make sure in all your service methods that you check for an authenticated user or you could leak some data (or worse, allow anyone to mutate it!)