# GWT RequestFactory logged user

Tags: session, gwt, requestfactory

I was searching for a complete simple example about logged user handling with GWT `RequestFactory`.

I found that I have to catch the `HTTPServletRequest` (server-side) with a command like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest();
```

but I can't imagine how to build the complete (client-side/server-side) `RequestFactory` invocation/response catching.

Can you provide some simple classes?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a servlet filter.

[GWT RequestFactory authentication functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047925/gwt-requestfactory-authentication-functions)

Have used this method in the past and it works great, also a great way to manage entity managers.

We use this and have a few different RequestFactory's that use different urls so that we can set the filter accordingly.

Comment: Ok, this can be a solution. But what I need is a simple RequestFactory fire event in which I can keep the user logged into Http Session. I see that the method getThreadLocalRequest() is a method of RequestFactoryServlet, but I cannot know how to use it into a call with Proxy/Entity and Request/Dao classes...