# GWT-RPC or RequestFactory for Authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, gwt, gwt-rpc, requestfactory

I'm trying to build a login screen for my GWT app. When you click the login button, the credentials (username & password) need to be sent to the server for authentication. I'm wondering what server communication method is a best fit for this: GWT-RPC or RequestFactory.

My *understanding* is the RequestFactory is more efficient and recommended over GWT-RPC, but it's more of a data/entity/persistence framework than a request-response framework like RPC. So although many GWT afficionados recommend using RequestFactory over GWT-RPC, I don't think RequestFactory can be used for this scenario. After all, I don't want to CRUD a login request, I want to send credentials to a server, perform secured authentication, and return a response to the client.

1. Am I correct? Is GWT-RPC my only option? or
2. Can RequestFactory be used. If so, how (need to see a code example of both client and server code)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either, although RF is very used with `EntityProxy`, it also is thought to work with `ValueProxy` which mean transmit any type. RF facilitates as well execution of remote procedures passing Proxy types or primitive types.

Said that, I would use the technology used primarily in my app. If you are using RPC send your login/password in a RPC request, but if you are using RF use it, so as you dont mix things, although you can mix RF, RPC, and plain Ajax without problems.

What you have to be aware of, is that normally, in applications requiring authentication you have to use a filter to check whether the user has a valid session when requesting RPC or RF, so in the case of sending a request for login, you have to jump somehow the auth filter.

Related with security, both scenarios are the same, you have to do the request in an https enabled environment.

[EDIT]

This could be the interface for the client and the remote implementation of a RF call for login, as you can see it is really easy, you can add any method you need to these classes:

```
@Service(value = LoginUserService.class)
public interface LoginUserRequest extends RequestContext {
  Request<Boolean> login(String username, String password);
}

public class LoginUserService {
   // Using static you dont need to provide a Locator for the service
   static Boolean login(String username, String password) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Related with auth filters for RF, you can take a look to this: [GWT RequestFactory authentication functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047925/gwt-requestfactory-authentication-functions)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer @Manolo (+1) - two followup questions: (1) I'd prefer to use RF but all the code examples I've found use EntityProxy and demonstrate how to persist data (which is not what I want to do). **So can you provide a code example of both client- and server-side code for doing a super-simple authentication using RF?** That, or point me to a code example that does this? And (2) I can't be the only person in the world who has ever tackled authentication in GWT...

Comment: If what you are saying (about circumventing the auth filter) is true, **there has to be a standard way of doing this. Any ideas/code examples you can point me to?** Thanks again!

Comment: And by "super simple authentication", let's pretend that the server code just does: `if(username.equals("randy") && password.equals("12345")) return true; else false;` If I can just see where that "authentication" fits into the server RF code, and then see how the client RF code calls it, I should be good to go!

Comment: Posted an implementation of login using RF

Answer (score 1):

With both technology you can send such information to server side, but as already you pointed out the RequestFactory is dedicated to entity management. In your case is better to use GWT-RPC because in order to only send the credentials server side, and eventually retrieve the authentication result, you don't need the RequestFactory surplus (delta transmission, entity management).

Comment: Thanks @Fedy2 (+1) - one quick followup: you mention that GWT-RPC is a "one way data transmission", and that makes me a bit concerned. I still need a 2-way transmission: 1 for the request (submitting the username/password) and 1 for the response (pass/fail). Is GWT-RPC still my best choice, or is there another method you would recommend **for authentication**? For example, I've heard of RequestBuilder, JSON/HTTP, JSONP, etc... thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, the sentence was ambiguous, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks again @Fedy2 (+1 again) - but I'm **still** not fully understanding. I need to make a synchronous request to the server, sending it a username and password, and I need the server to send a response (PASS or FAIL). Can I use GWT-RPC for this synchronous, 2-way communication, or does GWT-RPC only go in 1 direction, from client to server? Sorry for being annoying here, just trying to understand exactly what you're saying. Thanks again for all the help so far!

Comment: Corrected again the main response. The GWT-RPC is bidirectional, so yes you can send the credentials to the server side and retrieve back the authentication result.

Comment: @Fedy2, what RF is dedicated to entity management is not entirely true , it works well with entities, but actually it covers all use cases in an ajax app: services, entity and non-entity data objects.

Comment: You can use RF as GWT-RPC alternative, but it is born for data management: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

For authentication, I would (almost) always use RequestBuilder, i.e. a simple HTTP(S!) POST. Why? Because this way you can implement a general authentication mechanism, that can not only be used by GWT apps. You gain the flexibility to add a simple HTML login page, single sign-on, standard server-side mechanisms (e.g. Spring security), etc.

A simple GWT re-login dialog is also no problem with RequestBuilder - to submit just username/password, GWT-RPC or RF is simply not necessary.