# GWT DefaultRequestTransport: when/why to extend?

Tags: java, gwt, callback, subclass, requestfactory

I've seen several GWT code excerpts where the developer extended [`DefaultRequestTransport`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/client/DefaultRequestTransport.html) and gave it custom functionality. One such example is in [this SO question regarding authentication/login filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047925/gwt-requestfactory-authentication-functions). But I have seen several others besides this one example.

My question: when & why does someone need to extend this class and override its methods? (In other words, what does this class do, what services do its methods perform, and why would I need to customize them?)

In that one example, the `createRequestCallback` method was overridden. According to the Javadocs on that method, it's purpose is to:

> Create a RequestCallback that maps the HTTP response onto the TransportReceiver interface.

This is still sort of a cryptic explanation to me. Could someone please give me a layman's explanation for what scenarios it would be beneficial to extend this class and override 1+ of its methods?

Answer (score 2):

RequestFactory does not depend on a specific "transport" mechanism; it deals with JSON representations of requests and responses but the way they're exchanged and transferred is *out of scope*, and deferred to a `RequestTransport`.

The `DefaultRequestTransport` uses a `RequestBuilder` to a given (but configurable) URL; because it uses `RequestBuilder`, it can only be used in a GWT client (to be compiled to JavaScript). There's also the `UrlRequestTransport` which uses a `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and can be used on any client running in a JVM (a server making a call to another server, an Android application, a desktop Java application, etc.)

In theory (because I never tried it and never heard someone else tried it), you could make a `RequestTransport` that uses Comet or WebSockets, or whichever transport you'd like. Of course, the server side would have to be adapted too (`SimpleRequestProcessor` can easily reused outside the `RequestFactoryServlet`; this is a similar *separation of concerns*)

Back to `DefaultRequestTransport`: it uses `RequestBuilder` and provides a few hooks that you can override to customize how it works. The most common use-case is to intercept all requests to add some request header (e.g. credentials) and/or all responses to handle specific HTTP responses before decoding the JSON-encoded RequestFactory response (e.g. intercept "unauthorized" response to ask the user to sign in).
`DefaultRequestTransport` works as an adapter between the RequestFactory API and the `RequestBuilder` one, and `createRequestCallback` is one half of it responsible for adapting the response.

Answer (score 1):

In the example shown they need to extend DefaultRequestTransport in order to inspect all RF server responses and catch 401 status (SC_UNAUTHORIZED) which means that the request was rejected in the server side because the user has not a valid session, and then redirect the user to the application login page.

I've used DefaultRequestTransport as well for changing the requestUrl (the default is set to `gwtRequest`), so as I can set filters based on the url pattern: for instance authenticated RF services go to `/myapp/gwtRequest` or non-authenticated RF services go to  `/myapp/anonymousRequest` etc.

I also have a customized RequestTransport using modified versions of RequestBuilder and XMLHttpRequest able to monitor onprogress events, very helpful for large requests.

You could extend it to send customized headers used for doing CORS authentication or whatever.

In summary `RequestTransport` is the way to modify the client transport layer of RF.